# Which Yuga starts and which ends the Chatur-yuga? (Is Satya Yuga through to Kali Yuga right?)

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, time

Everyone, even if they don't say it seems to assume Satya Yuga starts the cycle and Kali Yuga ends it, but I have not seen any actual claim that that is true (actually scripture not having confirmation seems to imply it is not true). While the order things are listed often appears that way, it seems to always make sense it just means chronologically or saying cyclical appearances going backwards and only mentioning each once.

Is there any merit in the commonly held belief Kali Yuga is at the end and Satya Yuga is at the start?